# modal pop after a user click 3 times in any links on a site

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I am trying to make pop a modal window after a user as click on 3 different links on a site.
I am not too sure how to achieve it.
I am using this JS script to track the click

```
window.onload = function() {
    var clicked = readCookie('popunder');
    if(clicked == null) {
        clicked = 0;
    }

    if(clicked >= 3) {
        return;
    }

    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i=0;i<=allLinks.length;i++) {
        allLinks[i].addEventListener("click",countClicks,true);
    }

    function countClicks() {           
        if(clicked == 2) {
            popunder(); //something to do
        } else {
            clicked++;
            doCookie('popunder', clicked, 1);
            alert(clicked);
        }
    }

    function popunder() { alert('thats 3 clicks!'); }

    function doCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        } else {
            var expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var readName = name + "=";
        var cSplit = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < cSplit.length;i++) {
            var sc = cSplit[i];
            while (sc.charAt(0)==' ') sc = sc.substring(1,sc.length);
            if (sc.indexOf(readName) == 0) return sc.substring(readName.length,sc.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using ctools on a site to manage modal on a particular links but i don t know how to link this action on a 3rd click, which could be any link.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything `ctools` related in your code. Can you please point out the line(s) where Ctools is giving you trouble or what errors you're seeing?

Comment: Hello Molot
Thank you for your interest, and sorry for being confusing. (it is the first time i am posting something here).
I am thinking to use the script i post and ctools to fired off a modal after 3 click. i read ctools doc but i get a bit lost.
i simply just don't know how to integrate ctools with my script. i post the script to show what i am using.

hope this is clear enought , sorry if it is not

Comment: Hi welcome here, my name is Tenken by the way. The only advice I can give you integrating this custom script with Drupal is to review the Javascript API for Drupal https://www.drupal.org/node/751744 and the Drupal Javascript Documentation https://www.drupal.org/node/121997

Comment: Thanks Tenken i will look this way. i will keep updating with my progress and hopefully i will be able to share a solution.